# assigning array valued function to a cellArray

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a function `func(x)` which signature is

```
[v] = func(x)
```

where `v` is a function. I wanted to do the following, after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769960/array-of-arrays-in-matlab)

```
x= [1:10];
for i=1:length(x)
     v{i} = func(x(i));
end
```

and I got this error:

```
Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object.
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems v is already a vector, you have to initialise a cell:

```
v={}
```

or delete the vector:

```
clear v
```

Alternatively you can initialize a cell of the right size, which is faster because it allocates the memory at once:

```
v=cell(length(x),1);
```

Comment: I think the fact that `v` is a vector is irrelevant, I tried this also with "free" names and the result was the same.

Comment: @user42864: No, `v` being is vector is **very** relevant.  You cannot perform cell operations on a vector.  Even though MATLAB for the most part is type agnostic, cells and vectors are one of the few instances where you need to make sure that you apply the right syntax to the right kind of variable.  What @Daniel said is correct.  What I would suggest you do is initialize `v` to an empty cell array as suggested, then iterate through your loop. It would also help if you placed more code, as the error generated may be related to what is happening **before** your loop.

Comment: @rayryeng thanks, but the reasons I said it is irrelevant because I tried to run the same code with something like `u{i} = func(x(j))` and it still returned the same error, after the second iteration. I expected that in the first iteration I'd get that `u{1}` would be my first vector, `u{2}` the second etc. In that case it is clear from the first iteration that`u` is a cellaray rather then a vector, no?

Comment: @user42864: Please update your question and include example code for `func` which allows us to reproduce the problem. I assumed the `v{i} = func(x(i));` assignment causes the problem, but there might be another assignment which is not visible in your question.

Comment: @user42864: In that case, you should probably update your post with more relevant code.  Something is happening before that `for` block that is making the value of `v` not perform to what you are expecting.

Comment: my code for `func` is a heavy numerical simulation. I tried to reproduce it with something easier like `func(x) = [1:x]` but the problem didn't persist. Any idea on how can I share the function code without having you loaded with irrelevant code? (nothing secret, I'd be happy to show it as well)

Comment: @user42864 We don't need to see `func` I think.  We want to see what is happening **before** the `for` loop.

Comment: Guys, sorry for the trouble, but your remarks were ABSOLUTELY CORRECT while it was I who didn't check it properly. `v` was used somewhere else and couldn't be implicitly re-assigned. Thank, and sorry for the trouble :)

Comment: @user42864 aha, no worries.  However, FWIW, that syntax that you have is correct, provided that `v` is **not initialized** anywhere else, or if you reset the definition of `v` before the `for` loop.  You would only get that MATLAB error if `v` was already in your workspace and was a different type.